# Cannot retrieve validation settings

Tags: javascript, html, validation, model-view-controller

I am using validation on my MVC page and I need to disable the validation of the postcode field if the non-UK check box is checked.

I have the following code in my view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Postcode, new {@class = "col-sm-3 control-label"})
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Postcode, new {@type = "text", @class = "form-control"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Postcode)
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.IsNonUk, new {@class = "col-sm-3 control-label"})
         <div class="col-sm-9">
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsNonUk) 
         </div>
     </div>
```

and the following code in my Javascript:

```
    (function () {
        var val = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator');

        if (val != undefined) {
            var settngs = val.settings;
            settngs.ignore = ".ignore";
        } 

        $('#IsNonUk').change(function () {
            var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

            $(this).attr("value", isChecked);

            if (isChecked) {
                $("#Postcode").addClass("ignore");
            } else {
                $("#Postcode").removeClass("ignore");
            }
        });
    })();
```

The class ignore is successfully being added and removed from the postcode element - I have checked in Chrome's debugging tools - but the val that is attempting to retrieve the validation settings is returning undefined. I have searched for documentation on these settings but have been unable to find them (can anyone point me in the right direction?).

I have seen a few posts on stackoverflow, such as [jQuery Validation: $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575443/jquery-validation-dataform0-validator-settings-returns-undefined), but they don't help.

Why can't I retrieve the settings for my form? Please help!

M

**Update**

I have added some code to ensure the settings can be retrieved:

```
    $('#formCreateInvoice').ready(function () {
        var val = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator');

        if (val != undefined) {
            var settngs = val.settings;
            settngs.ignore = ".ignore";
        }
    })
```

This seems to work ok. I put some logging within the inner scope and it all works fine. If I check the box when the page first loads the validation is disabled as expected. If I leave the box unchecked when the page first loads then the validation is enabled as expected.

The problem seems to be adding and removing the ignore class. If I check the box and then validate the form, then I uncheck the box and revalidate the form, it doesn't work correctly. There seems to be some problem in picking up the ignore class from the postcode element. I would try stepping through the validation Javascript but I'm using VS2010 :(

Answer (score 0):

please replace your selector from this:

```
 $('#IsNonUk')
```

to that one:

```
 $('.col-sm-9>input')
```

the **id** of the checkbox is not IsNonUk.. it is just an input element inside a div with a **col-sm-9** class.. the selector select all the parent div's and for each one selects the input

Comment: As I say, I have checked in Chrome developer tools and the classes are being applied correctly. When the element is rendered, it is given and id of IsNonUk. The problem is not with that portion of the code - the problem is that the validator query is returning undefined.

Comment: I have now managed to get a validator object successfully but have another problem. Please see the update above.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue but it's a fudge:

```
    $('#IsNonUk').change(function () {
        var isChecked = $(this).is(":checked");

        $(this).attr("value", isChecked);

        if (isChecked) {
            $("#Postcode").addClass("ignore");
        } else {
            $("#Postcode").removeClass("ignore");
        }

        $('#formCreateInvoice').validate().resetForm();
        $("label.error").hide();
        $(".input-validation-error").removeClass("input-validation-error");
        $("span[id$='-error']").hide();
        $("span.field-validation-error").hide();
    });
```

It works, but I'd rather not go around removing classes and amending attributes that are generated by a library. Ho hum.

M